# Install yelp package using npm in meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, yelp

I am trying to install yelp package using npm in meteor.
 The commands provided is

```
 npm install yelp
```

in my config.js file

```
yelp = Npm.require("yelp")
```

But i am getting an error as

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
W20151022-13:28:11.884(5.5)? (STDERR)     at 
app/node_modules/yelp/node_modules/oauth/lib/_utils.js:2:1
 W20151022-13:28:11.884(5.5)? (STDERR)     at
app/node_modules/yelp/node_modules/oauth/lib/_utils.js:6:3
```

Is this the right way to add npm module in meteor. Or i have to define it somewhere else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package to add npm modules to your site:
https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm`

And read the documentation to see how to do it. Writing `npm` command in the terminal won't do anything to your Meteor project.